# Google Map Cluster moves when zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

I got an application with a Google Map and the clustering API.

I'm adding `ClusterItem`s like this:

```
MyClusterItem item = new MyClusterItem(optionMarkerToDraw);
clusterManager.addItem(item);
```

I got a renderer:

```
public class ClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyClusterItem>
{
    public ClusterRenderer()
    {
        super(getActivity(), map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyClusterItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions)
    {
        markerOptions.icon(item.getIcon());
        markerOptions.position(item.getPosition());
        markerOptions.alpha(item.getAlpha());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions)
    {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster,markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster)
    {
        //start clustering if at least 2 items overlap
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }
}
```

When the items are still not grouped into a cluster, they're showing fine on the map with no issues.

When the items ARE grouped into a cluster, there's an issue that when zooming in and out of the map, makes the cluster move to a different location on the map.

How can I make the cluster keep its location on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was with the algorithm. I had this line in the code:

```
clusterManager.setAlgorithm(new PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator<MGClusterItem>(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MGClusterItem>()));
```

That caused the behavior. After removing this line, the cluster stayed in its place like I expected.

Comment: i am facing the same problem with set Algorithm?

Comment: try using the same line as in my answer

Comment: @YonatanNir yes it's work. but when I use `DefaultClusterRenderer` render then it lot's of markers and click on any marker at that time some of cluster marker merge. but if I used `GridBasedAlgorithm` then issue is not coming but at that time cluster move any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Should change your algorithm for cluster manager

```
let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()

let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()

let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)

clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
```